# What is dnu wrap for?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dnx, .net-core

The documentation is unclear, it seems like it allows for wraping dlls and csproj for use in a Asp.Net Core 5 application.  Does it allow you to use class libraries built against .Net Framework 4.6 in a .Net Core 5 website?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that `dnu wrap` allows you to pull in legacy code into ASP.NET 5 applications that are targeting the right frameworks.  All `dnu wrap` is doing here is creating a project.json for the dll/csproj and if you're running via Visual Studio then also a reference to that project.json (but you can add the reference manually).

Because no code is actually changing here (or dependencies etc), you cannot use `dnu wrap` to pull in assemblies that target a runtime that your project does not otherwise target and expect it to build, unless of course you update your project to target that runtime and reference any required dependencies.

Thats all it does.

From `dnu --help`;

> Wrap a csproj/assembly into a project.json, which can be referenced by
>   project.json files.

Comment: Thanks!  Why do you need to create a project.json for an assembly that is targeting the correct framework already?

Comment: @rjdevereux because dnx doesn't know what a csproj is or how they work.  The project.json is to allow dnx to compile/include the project in a format it understands.